# Slick slider with Magnific Popup Lightbox Gallery

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I have multiple thumbnail images with slick slider which I also want to be opened using a lightbox gallery for a bigger sized image.

The slick slider works great and the lightbox does open but it will not detect the gallery function. How to edit the current Magnific Popup Jquery so it will detect the gallery?

```
jQuery('.popup-gallery').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).magnificPopup({
        delegate: 'a',
        type: 'image',
        tLoading: 'Loading image #%curr%...',
        mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
        gallery: {
        enabled: true,
        navigateByImgClick: true,
        preload: [0,1], // Will preload 0 - before current, and 1 after the current image
        arrowMarkup: '<button title="%title%" type="button" class="mfp-arrow mfp-arrow-%dir%"></button>', // markup of an arrow button
      }
    });
  });
```

Here's a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3vyp3bzm/) for my current code.

Answer (score 2):

Use [slick-lightbox](https://github.com/mreq/slick-lightbox) which works great out of the box along with slick.

Imagine you have a complex slick slider like this,

```
    $('.yourslider').slick({
     dots: false,
     infinite: true,
     arrows: true,
     slidesToShow: 6,
     slidesToScroll: 1,
     pauseOnHover: false,
     autoplay: false,
     autoplaySpeed: 1000,
     responsive: [
       {
         breakpoint: 1024,
         settings: {
           slidesToShow: 6,
           slidesToScroll: 1,
           infinite: true,
           dots: false
         }
       },
       {
         breakpoint: 600,
         settings: {
           slidesToShow: 4,
           slidesToScroll: 1
         }
       },
       {
         breakpoint: 480,
         settings: {
           slidesToShow: 2,
           slidesToScroll: 1
         }
       }
     ]
     });
```

Then you only add:

```
$('.yourslider').slickLightbox({
    src: 'src',
itemSelector: 'div img',
navigateByKeyboard  : true,
captionPosition     : 'dynamic',
caption            : 'name'
});
```

And you are ready to go, just an amazing tool!

Comment: great! only you need to wrap it in `$(document).ready(function(){` `});`